# How to create a date directory in a subfolder

Tags: php

i am trying to create a date/year/month directory in myupload folder. but it is created on ROOT folder. Second problem is that the created directory is one day back. I think its a timezone problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su3T0.png) (image attached)

```
<?php 
if (!file_exists(date("Y")))
    mkdir(date("Y")); 

if (!file_exists(date("Y").'/'.date("m")))
    mkdir(date("Y").'/'.date("m"));

if (!file_exists(date("Y").'/'.date("m").'/'.date("d")))folder
    mkdir(date("Y").'/'.date("m").'/'.date("d"));

$path= './rshq/myupload/'.'/'.date("Y/m").'/'; ?>
```

Comment: I think this is a bad idea, file headers already have the date to which they where created on your server. You should combine this with a database, storing pointers to your files in order to fetch them.

Comment: You mkdir a directory without any path. Of course you create on root.

Comment: @ Xorifelse Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: @ Vincent Decaux Thanks for your valuable feedback.